# Unique Factorization for cubes in Z[sqrt(-d)]

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $d=1,2$. Show that if $ab$ is a cube in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt(-d)]$ and $a,b$ are coprime $\implies a,b$ are cubes in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt(-d)]$.

I know $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt(-d)]$ has unique factorization and gcd($a,b) = 1$. So far I only have:

$ab = (x+y\sqrt(-d))^3 = a_1\cdot\cdot\cdot a_nb_1\cdot\cdot\cdot b_n$ where each $a_i,b_j$ is prime. However, i don't see how to use the fact $a,b$ are coprime to get my desired result.

Comment: Now that I think about it, since $ab = x+y\sqrt(-d)$ I can say the LHS is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}\sqrt(-d)$. So the only thing left to show is that $a,b$ are cubes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there exists a $c \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$ such that $ab= c^3$. Let $p_1^{e_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n^{e_n}$ denote the prime factorization of $c$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$. Then $ab = p_1^{3e_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n^{3e_n}$ and for each $k=1,\ldots,n$ we know that $p_k$ must divide $a$ or $b$. If $p_i$ divides both $a$ and $b$, then $a$ and $b$ are no longer coprime, hence $p_k^{3e_k}$ divides $a$ xor $b$
$$a = \prod_{i\::\:p_k|a} p^{3e_k}_{k}\quad\text{and}\quad \prod_{i\::\:p_k|b} p^{3e_k}_k.$$

Comment: Perfect. That makes perfect sense. Thank you.